# How to take document on event handler except one class in document using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I need to take whole document in mousemove event except one class in document using jQuery

My class is `no-mousemove-node`.

```
$(document).mousemove(
        function(e){  
        ....
});.
```

I tried like below, but no working

```
$(document).not('.no-mousemove-node').mousemove(
        function(e){  
        ....
});.
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`e.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) inside your event handler to see if the source element matches your criteria, and abort execution if it does not:

```
$(document).mousemove(
    function(e){  
        if ($(e.target).is(".no-mousemove-node")) return;
        // now do what you need
    }
});
```

**Update:** if you need to also filter out descendants of `.no-mousemove-node` use `.closest` to determine if you are, or have a parent that is, a `.no-mousemove-node`:

```
function(e){  
    if ($(e.target).closest(".no-mousemove-node").length) return;
}
```

Comment: In webpage contains some containers  with class `no-mousemove-node`. They contains inner elements also. So `e.target` will be on inner node classes. How to sort this issue?